# Actionscript Graph API: Requesting publish_stream extended permission WHEN USER ALREADY LOGGED IN

Tags: facebook, flash, permissions

How do I in the latest Actionscript Graph API,

force user to allow publish_stream

When : We are doing a facebook timeline app and I need to be able to post an application link

But: The User does not login via app but via site directly so I can NOT do

```
Facebook.login(handleLogin,["publish_stream]);
```

-- Nothing happens as we are already logged in

Comment: I dont know anything in regards to facebook API, but maybe it could have something to do with session times, cookies ect

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if you got this error just on copy and paste here, but...

you try this:

```
 Facebook.login(handleLogin,["publish_stream"]);
```

instead this:

```
 Facebook.login(handleLogin,["publish_stream]);
```

cya,
have a nice coding